# How to I query multiple addresses in google places with only one API call?

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I have a list of places that I need to get reviews and a street view photo for using Google Places API. These will be displayed on a website that I am developing. I know how to query just one place but I have up to 100 places that I need to get information on. I would like to get this with just one API call if possible. I have the address, longitude, and latitude of each location currently.

I have already looked at the documentation on Google's site https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search.

I would like to be able to take the results returned and use them to populate an infowindow on my website's google map for each of the locations.

Answer (score 0):

I recently worked on third party api which provides the location data. [FourSquare](https://developer.tomtom.com/) and [TomTom](https://developer.foursquare.com/places-api) and none of them provided bulk api to get the data. Here Bulk means passing multiple lat long and get the location detail with matched search.

At the end we have to loop over the location and call the api multiple times. If google api that you are using is paid service than you can ask to support team.

Comment: Have you tried Batch Search from TomTom APIs? https://developer.tomtom.com/search-api/search-api-documentation/batch-search
Please also correct links because they are not attributed correctly.